# R data wrangling do not do the function in the whole dataset

Tags: r, dataset, lubridate, data-wrangling

I am preparing a dataset for futher analysis. For this I do a timeshift -days(60) and write the result in a new column. Not difficult normally, but the computer is not doing it completly. A few rows where not calculated.

```
df$acquisition_time=as.POSIXct(df$acquisition_time, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")
df$acqui_timeshift <- df$acquisition_time - days(60)
```

Here I put a screenshot where you see the problem:
[image]

the "NA" in the corner continues further. The dataset is 1,3 Million rows. So maybe the computerpower is not enough?
There is no ERROR: or WARNING: from R

it would be nice if someone can help me with this strange problem!

Thanks a lot!

Best, Christian

```
    data<- structure(list(ani_id_year = c("982_year2019", "982_year2019", 
"985_yearNA", "996_yearNA"), month = c("02", "02", "05", "05"
), year = c(2020, 2020, 2018, 2018), year_ts = c(2019, 2019, 
NA, NA), acquisition_time = structure(c(1581310879, 1581782462, 
1527120030, 1527120052), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
    day = c("02-10", "02-15", "05-24", "05-24"), x = c(382992.722829081, 
    384653.805434133, 387585.792076463, 388305.553482353), y = c(5419798.49669287, 
    5420068.44700148, 5411757.45423474, 5401584.90172328), groupid = c(3L, 
    3L, 3L, 2L), name = c(982L, 982L, 985L, 996L), name_echte = c("Tana", 
    "Tana", "Zita", "Berta"), nr = c(1351995L, 1352125L, 
    1370437L, 1278038L)), row.names = c(1256187L, 1256317L, 1281322L, 
1343545L), class = "data.frame")
```

sorry I really do not know how to add this here, I used dpud() to get the code..

Comment: Can you add a reproducible example? You did not link the data, so we can only guess what is going wrong.

Comment: You seem to use `View()` to look at your data. In big datasets can have trouble/delays in showing stuff when you scroll down. To check whether there are *actually* lots of missings in `acqui_timeshift`, use `sum(is.na(df$acqui_timeshift))`.

Comment: @PLY I did my best, I am not able to put the table right is there a simple tool doing this?  @benimwolfspelz yes i tried this and there are NAs, also while I am continue  working with the table ````df$aquitimeshift```?  ...

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to reproduce the same error using what has been provided. But, I can confirm that the way you're calculating `acqui_timeshift` works. (If you filter the input data down to only those observations that result in `acqui_timeshift` is `NA` and provide that filtered data as a reproducible example, I can retry here.)

**Using `data` currently provided**

```
# Method 1 - Using lubridate days() ----------------------------------------

df$acquisition_time <- as.POSIXct(df$acquisition_time, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")
df$acqui_timeshift <- df$acquisition_time - days(60)

#           ani_id_year   acquisition_time    acqui_timeshift
# 1256187   982_year2019  2020-02-10 05:01:19 2019-12-12 05:01:19
# 1256317   982_year2019  2020-02-15 16:01:02 2019-12-17 16:01:02
# 1281322   985_yearNA    2018-05-24 00:00:30 2018-03-25 00:00:30
# 1343545   996_yearNA    2018-05-24 00:00:52 2018-03-25 00:00:52

# Method 2 - Using base R difftime() ----------------------------------------

df$acquisition_time = as.POSIXct(df$acquisition_time, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")
df$acqui_timeshift <- df$acquisition_time - as.difftime(60, unit="days")

#           ani_id_year  acquisition_time    acqui_timeshift
# 1256187   982_year2019 2020-02-10 05:01:19 2019-12-12 05:01:19
# 1256317   982_year2019 2020-02-15 16:01:02 2019-12-17 16:01:02
# 1281322   985_yearNA   2018-05-24 00:00:30 2018-03-25 00:00:30
# 1343545   996_yearNA   2018-05-24 00:00:52 2018-03-25 00:00:52
```

**Singling out the `aquisition_time` that had produced `NA` in your screenshot**

```
# Method 1 - Using lubridate days() ----------------------------------------

as.POSIXct("2019-05-30 02:00:38", tz = "UTC", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS") - days(60)
# "2019-03-31 02:00:38 UTC"

# Method 2 - Using base R difftime() ----------------------------------------

as.POSIXct("2019-05-30 02:00:38", tz = "UTC", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS") - as.difftime(60, unit="days")
# "2019-03-31 02:00:38 UTC"
```